# Rails Devise Invitable gem resend invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I need to resend invitations to users on my app.  I know [Devise Invitable](https://stackoverflow.com) has a `resend_invite` method, so calling `invite!` will resend a new invitation with a new token, but my question is how do I actually code the form?

It would be good to make the form `remote: true` so I can put it in a few places on the application that it's needed, but how do I code a custom form button or link_to text that I could inject into the code base.  Anything that will eventually call `User.invite!`

Right now, I have this atrocity:

```
<% resource = access_list.user %>
        <% resource_name = :user %>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :resend_invite, value: true %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :resend_user, value: access_list.user.id %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "resend invite" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

that touches this:

```
def update
        if params[:user][:resend_invite] == "true"
            @resend_user = User.find(params[:user][:resend_user])
            @resend_user.invite!
            flash[:alert] = "We've resent an email invitation to #{@resend_user.email}"
        end
            
    super
    
  end
```

Which works, but is obviously the worst way to do it since it's just piggybacking off the devise controller, not the devise_invitable controller.  How do I make it touch the devise_invitable controller?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.